# ESLint: How Do I tell eslint to ignore a coldfusion comment

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, eslint

We are using ESLint and the ESlint HTML plugin.  We are running into an issue where we are using a coldfusion comment 
`<!---`
and eslint is parsing everything inside the comment as if it is javascript.  Is there a way to tell eslint to ignore everything between 
`<!--- and --->`

Comment: Are you dynamically generating Javascript with CF? A ColdFusion comment isn't valid Javascript and probably should be flagged, just like an HTML comment in Javascript. Javascript has its own flavor for comments.

Comment: The coldfusion comment never gets to the browser so it is not really violating any JS lint rules

Comment: How do you use eslint? Do you use an HTML plugin and configure `.cfm` file extension to be considered HTML code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to configure ESLint to do this automatically, but you should be able to wrap your CF comments with ESLint [configuration comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) to disable linting for that block.

```
/* eslint-disable */
<!---
...
--->
/* eslint-enable */
```